# NSUserDefults returns null

Tags: objective-c, ios, nsuserdefaults

I save a custom object in NSUserDefults the object has more than one property ,
 i initialize the value of the custom object in the AppDelegate ,
 my problem is that when i try to retrieve the custom object property "userToken"  in the viewcontroller didLoad method it works and the data is correct but when i retrieve it in another method in the view controller i get NULL  note that  the other property "uId" returns the correct value and i'm retrieving the objects in same way

what did i do wrong here ?  help is really appreciated

here's how i save and retrieve the object

```
+(void)SaveUser:(User *)user
{
    NSUserDefaults *userDefaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    NSData *userData = [NSKeyedArchiver archivedDataWithRootObject:user];
    [userDefaults setObject:userData forKey:@"User"];  
    [userDefaults synchronize]; 
}

+(User*)retrieveUser
{
    NSUserDefaults *ud = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    NSData *userData = [ud objectForKey:@"User"];
    User *user = [NSKeyedUnarchiver unarchiveObjectWithData:userData];
    return user;    
}
```

and here's the implementation of the User object

```
- (id)initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)decoder 
{
   self = [super init];
   if (self)
   {    
        //uId and userToken are of type NSString
        self.uId = [decoder decodeObjectForKey:@"UID"];
        self.userToken = [decoder decodeObjectForKey:@"DeviceToken"];
   }
   return self;
}

- (void)encodeWithCoder:(NSCoder *)encoder 
{
    [encoder encodeObject:self.uId forKey:@"UID"];
    [encoder encodeObject:self.userToken forKey:@"DeviceToken"];
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this :
Also note that  + mean as static function that didn't have access to class properties make every thing in your saveuser or retrieveuser functions also decode without call another method out of class to decode it . that why maybe your + method get always null value when you use it out of loadview

```
+(void)SaveUser:(User *)user
{
    NSUserDefaults *UserDefaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    [UserDefaults setObject:[NSKeyedArchiver archivedDataWithRootObject:user] forKey:@"User"];
    [UserDefaults synchronize];
}

+(User*)retrieveUser
{
    NSUserDefaults *UserDefaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    NSData *userData = [UserDefaults objectForKey:@"User"];
    User *user = [NSKeyedUnarchiver unarchiveObjectWithData:userData];
    return user;
}
```

Comment: thnx but the methods SaveUser: and retrieveUser are a part of a Utility class hence the + ,, these methods are not a part of the User class !

Comment: the methods that you are use initWithCoder and encodeWithCoder if you tried to put them in utility class as you doing with always get null because you can't access properties of static class .. so if you are using only these two function -SaveUser retrieveUser-  from utility class or even application delegate it will work because they work for me for any call inside or outside viewdidload..

Comment: thnx for baring with me here ,but that's exactly what i'm doing the initWithCoder end encodeWithCoder are not in the utility class they are in the User class , what's driving me crazy that sometimes it works and sometimes it just returns null !

Comment: well i kinda of found a solution , i still didn't figure out what is wrong i just changed the method from where i'm calling the retrieveUser method ! thnx a lot @Mina